# Android :Use android binding click event on custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-binder

I have created custom view. My class extended from `RelativeLayout` and in my class i created button and progressbar views and added these views to my class:

```
public class CircleProgressButton extends RelativeLayout {...

private void initView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.ProgressButton, 0, 0
    );
    try {
        progressHeight = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_height, progressHeight);
        progressWidth = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_width, progressWidth);
        progressIconSuccess = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_iconSuccess, R.drawable.ic_done);
        progressIconFail = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_iconfail, R.drawable.ic_fail);
        progressText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_text);
        progressBackgroundImage = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.ProgressButton_progress_button_background);
    } finally {
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    initButton();
    initProgressBar();
    initImageView();
}
```

I use of my class in a *MarhalehFragment* like this:

```
<com.tazik.circleprogressbutton.CircleProgressButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_save"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    app:progress_height="30"
                    app:progress_width="30"
                    app:progress_text = "@string/save_btn"
                    app:progress_iconfail="@drawable/ic_fail"
                    app:progress_iconSuccess="@drawable/ic_done"
                    app:progress_button_background="@drawable/mybutton"
                    android:onClick="@{handlers::onSaveClicked}"/>
```

As you can see i used android binding `@{handlers::onSaveClicked}` for my custom view:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="handlers"
            type="com.tazik.engineer.fragment.MarhalehFragment.ClickHandlers" />
    </data>
```

In main fragment i binding it's Layout

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_marhaleh, container, false);
```

and create instance of my handler class and added to binding:

```
binding.setHandlers(new ClickHandlers());
```

this is my ClickHandler class:

```
public class ClickHandlers {

    public void onSaveClicked(View view) {
        saved = true;
        Log.i("======", "onSaveClicked: ");
    }
```

But when i click on my custom view by `android:onClick="@{handlers::onSaveClicked}"` , `onSaveClicked` in  *ClickHandlers* not triggered? My handler class and my binding does not any problem because i have other button and it's clicked trigger own method in ClickHandlers.

What is my problem?

Comment: binding has many issues like that, and not easy to understand, try to use kotlin, far better from it

Comment: If i use simple button i do not have any problem but i make a custom view and i want to use in my project ... i stuck yet @LakhwinderSingh

Comment: did you try `@{()->handlers.onSaveClick()}`?

Comment: I try to use your suggestion bu i got this `error:msg:cannot find method onSaveClicked() in class com.......fragment.MarhalehFragment.ClickHandlers
  file:D:\Projects\....\src\main\res\layout\fragment_marhaleh.xml` .I have onSaveClicked() in my handler class @ZohaibAmir

Comment: @sayreskabir pass in the view as your function is taking view parameter `@{(view)->handlers.onSaveClick(view)}`

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda in onClick attribute since you are using a data binding expression and the expression must have valid Java Code:

```
 android:onClick="@{(view)->handlers.onSaveClicked(view)}"
```